# Valid situations for comparing shared_ptr instances

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, equality

Under what situations would it be valid to compare shared_ptr instances instead of the underly lying type the shared_ptr manages?

As an example, would there ever be a situation where the size of personset being 2 would be valid after the following code has run?

```
shared_ptr<person> p0 = make_shared<person>(....);
shared_ptr<person> p1 = p0;

set<shared_ptr<person>> personset;

personset.insert(p0);
personset.insert(p1);
```

Comment: If you want to have two then perhaps use a multiset?

Comment: @flatmouse yeah I guess so, but my question was about the kinds of situations where we'd be interested in the actual instance of shared_ptr and not what it actually points to.

Comment: Sounds like a philosophical question or maybe an X-Y problem.

Comment: I find the question useful, but I wonder how it came up. Why would comparing `shared_ptr`s mean anything else than "do these point to the same object" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no viable reason to compare the instances. Infact shared_ptrs by default will perform equality/inequality comparators based via the underlying pointer to the control block (via .get method).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp